# wchar_t vs wint_t

Tags: c, string

This is an ANSI C question. I have the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

  int main()
  {
    if (!setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")) {
      printf( "Can't set the specified locale! "
              "Check LANG, LC_CTYPE, LC_ALL.\n");
      return -1;
    }
    wint_t c;
    while((c=getwc(stdin))!=WEOF)
      {
    printf("%lc",c);
      }
    return 0;
  }
```

I need full UTF-8 support, but even at this simplest level, can I improve this somehow? Why is `wint_t` used, and not `wchar`, with appropriate changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UTF-8` is one possible encoding for Unicode. It defines 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes per character. When you read it through [`getwc()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/wchar.h.html), it will fetch one to four bytes and compose from them a single Unicode character *codepoint*, which would fit within a `wchar` (which can be 16 or even 32 bits wide, depending on platform).

But since Unicode values map to all of the values from `0x0000` to `0xFFFF`, there are no values left to return condition or error codes in. (Some have pointed out that Unicode is larger than 16 bits, which is true; in those cases [surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description) are used. But the point here is that Unicode uses *all* of the available values leaving none for EOF.)

Various error codes include EOF (`WEOF`), which maps to -1. If you were to put the return value of `getwc()` in a `wchar`, there would be no way to distinguish it from a Unicode `0xFFFF` character (which, BTW, is reserved anyway, but I digress).

So the answer is to use a *wider* type, an `wint_t` (or `int`), which holds at least 32 bits.  That gives the lower 16 bits for the real value, and anything with a bit set outside of that range means something other than a character returning happened.

**Why don't we always use `wchar` then instead of `wint`? Most string-related functions use `wchar` because on most platforms it's ½ the size of `wint`, so strings have a smaller memory footprint.**

Comment: An UTF-8 character can be 4 bytes long, technical it can even take 5 or 6 bytes, but such compositions are not valid utf8 characters.

Comment: Well, true. It can be 4 bytes long if you go into the extra plan characters of 0x10000 and higher, but that gets into surrogates when dealing with UTF-16, and I thought it outside the scope of the question. And while 5 or 6 byte sequences are possible, they can always be expressed in fewer than 5 bytes, and are only generated by poor-quality serializers.

Comment: Your answer is mostly correct, but you provide too many (platofrm depenent) details. `wchar_t` is _not_ always 16 bits, I can think of at least 2 OS/compiler combinations where it's 32.

Comment: Thanks. I was referring to the character itself needing 16 bits, but I can see now the ambiguity. Clarified, and also for wint_t.

Comment: "_all of the Unicode values map to `0x0000` to `0xFFFF`_" … this is wrong. Valid Unicode values range from `0` to `0x10FFFF`; see <http://unicode.org/glossary/#code_point>.

Comment: @musiphil Yes, I know. What I meant is that there are valid Unicode codepoints for all of those values. Instead of voting down, you could just clarify the point so that anyone in the future can get the point without trying to follow the thread of comments.

Comment: @lavinio: I didn't vote down on anything in this thread, so don't hate me. :) Thank you for modifying your answer to make the point clearer!

Comment: @LoganCapaldo: Actually, Windows is the only platform I know of where `wchar_t` is 16-bit. Pretty much *all* other platforms have 32-bit `wchar_t` (but in a conforming implementation it can be anything, down to 8-bit).

Comment: *"because on most platforms it's ½ the size of wint, so strings have a smaller memory footprint."* - this rationale is completely **wrong**, and misses the whole point. `wchar_t` is not a size "optimization" at all! Using `wint_t` to *store* wide chars would be *wrong*, as it would allow *invalid* characters. The whole paragraph, or at least the emphasis, should be removed.

Comment: Downvoted because this answer contains plenty of wrong and misleading information, and fails to explain the `wint_t` type in a simple way. `wint_t` is solely to accomodate the additional `WEOF` value so that `getwc()` and friends can indicate failure conditions. Thus, `wint_t` _might_ be wider than `wchar_t` but could also be the same. `wchar_t` may be as wide as `char`. Also, `EOF` is some arbitrary negative value. Stating that it is -1 leads to non-portable code. All this is completely implementation-specific. By talking about how Unicode encodings work you completely missed the topic.

Comment: I'm surprise that nobody has pointed that the fact: ISO/ANSI C *never* mandates any kinds of Unicode on `wchar_t`. If someone want Unicode in C, `char16_t`/`char32_t` should be considered (though without many useful function available, e.g. no `getuc`).

Comment: @MestreLion Your explanation is also somewhat wrong. For platforms that use `wchar_t` which has more than 21 bits in its value representation, it may also allow invalid Unicode codepoints range out of [U+0, U+10FFFF]. The type `wint_t` is wrong to store the character just because of nominal reason: it is not designed to be the "right" type, as `int` is not designed to store characters normally.

Comment: @TimČas As a complement to your comment, Android's bionic uses 8-bit `wchar_t` (which surely can't support any useful Unicode encoding in a "wide" character form at all).

Comment: @FrankHB: (w.r.t.: ISO/ANSI C not mandating Unicode) True that, but w.r.t. the `wchar_t` vs `wint_t` purpose, the standard must be written so that it *can* also be done. So, to be fully correct, `wchar_t` being ***possibly*** Unicode is one of the reasons for `wint_t`. On a side-note, stdC does *explicitly* permit Unicode --- in this case, `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is defined (though this does not always conform in that it's often undefined even when Unicode is used for `wchar_t`!). And I didn't know about Bionic! Though it makes sense for them not wanting two diff. impls of most string functions.

Comment: @TimČas Good point about `__STDC_ISO_10646__`. (Though I can hardly find it in real code...)

Comment: On "most platforms" wchar_t is 32-bit, and wint_t is unsigned and no wider, and WEOF is not -1, so this answer is *packed* with misinformation.

Answer (score 26):

`wint_t` is capable of storing any valid value of `wchar_t`. A `wint_t` is also capable of taking on the result of evaluating the `WEOF` macro (note that a `wchar_t` might be too narrow to hold the result).

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, in brief: when is it better to use wchar_t then? Why not always use wint_t?

Comment: `wint_t` is to `wchar_t` what `int` is to `char`. We don't use arrays of `int`'s for narrow strings, even though `getc()` returns `int` to be able to return `EOF`. Similarly, we don't use arrays of `wint_t`'s for wide strings, even though `getwc()` returns `wint_t` to be able to return `WEOF`.

Comment: @musiphil: your comment deserves to be an answer, it's the only one that talks about the *conceptual* difference between them.

Answer (score 10):

As @musiphil has put so nicely in his comment, which I'll try to expand here, there is a *conceptual* difference between `wint_t` and `wchar_t`.

Their different sizes are a technical aspect that derives from the fact each one has very distinct *semantics* from the other:

- `wchar_t` is large enough to store a *character*, a *code unit* in Unicode parlance. As such, they are *unsigned*. They are analogous to `char`, which was large enough to store an *ASCII* character. So wide-char *strings* are arrays or pointers of `wchar_t`.
- Now enter string *functions*, some of which need to be able to return *any* `wchar_t` and also additional *statuses*. So their return type *must* be larger than `wchar_t`. Thus `wint_t` is used, which can express any wide char and *also* `WEOF`. Being a status, it can be *negative* (and it usually is), hence `wint_t` is most likely *signed*. I say "likely" because the C standard does not *mandate* it to be. But regardless of sign, status values need to be *outside* the range of `wchar_t`. They are only useful as return values, and never meant to be *stored* along such characters.

The analogy with "classic" `char` and `int` is great to clear any confusion: strings are not of type `int []`, they are `char var[]` (or `char *var`). Not to *"have a smaller memory footprint"*, but because that's what a string *is*.

Your code looks correct: `c` is used to check the result of `getwch()` so it is `wint_t`. And if its value is not `WEOF`, as your `if` tests, then it's safe to assign it to a `wchar_t` character (or a string array, pointer, etc)

Comment: Hmmmm  Disagree: C11 Spec says `wint_t` can be signed or unsigned.  Further it says "The value of the macro `WEOF` may differ from that of `EOF` and need not be negative."

Comment: `wchar_t` is not necessarily large enough to store code points.  Notably, on Windows it is only 16 bits, which means that the use of surrogate pairs is required in order to represent code points outside of the basic multilingual plane.

Comment: Each surrogate pair in UTF-16 is comprised of two 16-bit code units, not code points.  A code point does not fit in a wchar_t on Windows.

Comment: In terms of terminology, @rdb is correct (emphasis mine): ["Code points from the other planes (called Supplementary Planes) are _encoded as two 16-bit code units_ called surrogate pairs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF).

Comment: @rdb: I've corrected my answer to reflect this

Comment: There's actually nothing in the standard to suggest that `wchar_t` represents, or should be able to contain a Unicode code unit, or even be larger than `char`, so it would be correct only to say that `wchar_t` contains a character "from the extended character set", which may not be UTF-16 code units. Also no mandate that `wint_t` can represent any value of `wchar_t` (just any value from the extended character set). Note that on GCC, `wint_t` is unsigned int, and same size as `wchar_t`.

Comment: The C standard might not dictate what _actual_ "extended character set" `wchar_t` should represent, but I believe all implementations make it suitable to store at least Unicode code units, if not Unicode code _points_ directly. I'm not sure how to express that in a concise way so the answer does not deviate too much from its main point. Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: About `wint_t` and GCC, thanks to your comment I did some research and now I'm confused: [in GCC `WEOF` is of type **`int`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/EOF-and-Errors.html), and has a value of `-1`. How so? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39658503/624066) says the C standard mandates `WEOF` to be `wint_t`. Also, if it mandates `wchar_t` is large enough to accomodate `WEOF` (as long as it does not clash with an actual character), what would be the point of `wint_t`?

Comment: @MestreLion I tested it with a little program to print the value of WEOF under GCC and got `4294967295`, I guess the documentation is inaccurate. `wchar_t` is _not_ guaranteed to be able to accomodate `WEOF`, even if it could under a particular platform or choice of `WEOF`, hence the existence of `wint_t`.