# Inconsistency in definitions of fputwc(), putwc() and putwchar() in glibc

Tags: c, glibc, wchar-t

Why `fputwc()`, `putwc()` and `putwchar()` take argument of type `wchar_t` instead of `wint_t`?
This contradicts corresponding non-wide character functions `fputc()`, `putc()` and `putchar()`, *which take `int`, not `char`*.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `wchar_t` is required to hold an `WEOF` value and `char` is not required to hold an `EOF` value.

For `char`, the `fputc()`, `putc()` and `putchar()` functions need to accept values which can hold both values in the `unsigned char` *and* `EOF` range, where `EOF` can be a negative number so a `int` is required to hold them both.<sup>1</sup>

Whereas `wchar_t` itself is required to hold a `WEOF` character *as well* as the biggest locale.<sup>2</sup>  `WEOF` represents a value which fits inside `wchar_t` but doesn't overlap with any locale.<sup>3</sup>

This is made more confusing because of the the names of `char` and `wchar_t`, you shouldn't see `wchar_t` as a `char` but more as a `int` which size isn't dependent on the architecture but on the size of the biggest locale (and on the value of `WEOF`).<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> [Why putchar, toupper, tolower, etc. take a int instead of a char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452847/why-putchar-toupper-tolower-etc-take-a-int-instead-of-a-char/17453357#17453357)

<sup>2</sup> Quoting *ISO/IEC 9899:201x* 7.19.2:

> `WEOF`
>   which   expands   to   a   constant   expression   of   type
>   `wint_t` whose   value   does   not correspond to any member of the extended character set. It is accepted (and returned) by several functions in this subclause to indicate *end-of-file*, that is, no more input from a
>   stream.  **It is also used as a wide character value that does not correspond to any member of the extended character set.**

<sup>3</sup> [Quoting your link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extended-Char-Intro.html):

> The macro `WEOF` evaluates to a constant expression of type `wint_t` **whose value is different from any member of the extended character set.**

<sup>4</sup> [Quoting C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wchar_t/):

> `wchar_t`
>   Type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales.
>
> In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), `wchar_t` is a distinct fundamental type (and thus it is not defined in `<cwchar>` nor any other header).
>
> In [c](/questions/tagged/c), this is a `typedef` of an integral type.

Comment: Why in this C code gcc issues no warning? `void f(char c) {} void main(void) {f((int)65);}` Isn't there argument type mismatch? Why the following code does not issue no warning either? `...putwchar(getwchar());...` According to the definitions, argument of `putwchar` is of type **wchar_t**, but return value of `getwchar` is of type **wint_t**. Again - type mismatch. Why the warning is not produced by the compiler?

Comment: If **wchar_t** is required to hold an `WEOF` value, why **wint_t** exists?

Comment: What is the exact value of `WEOF`? Quoting the link http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extended-Char-Intro.html: "ISO 10646 was designed to be a 31-bit large code space". So according to your answer `WEOF` must occupy the place of some valid iso10646 character. This is a contradiction with `EOF`: its value was chosen not to coincide with any valid 8-bit character. Please explain why `WEOF` value is taken from the range of valid iso10646 characters.

Comment: You say that `wchar_t` must hold the value of `WEOF`. But gcc reference says that "WEOF evaluates to a constant expression of type wint_t whose value is different from any member of the extended character set". This is a contradiction.

Comment: `wchar_t` is not a member of the extended character set, it is a type which should represent all the character sets _and_ `WEOF`. The C standard (_9899:201x_ 7.29) also mentions: "`wchar_t` and `wint_t` can be the same integer type."

Comment: Now I understand: ISO 10646 code space takes only 31 bits. But wchar_t (and wint_t) is 32 bits. So, we have 1 extra bit to store WEOF value. But still, having **wchar_t** *and* **wint_t** is confusing. Isn't it? Even if they both exist, shouldn't there be some consistency in using them, but not spontaneously substituting one for another?

Comment: I think that this inconsistency should be reported to glibc developers, because if `wint_t` and `wchar_t` are the same anyway, it is better to be consistent in the function interfaces than to bring confusion. What is your opinion on whether this is worth being reported?

Comment: The first part of the first sentence in your answer is false.