# Why argument type of `putchar()`, `fputc()` and `putc()` is not `char`?

Tags: c, standards, glibc, c-standard-library

Does anybody know Why argument type of `putchar()`, `fputc()` and `putc()` is not `char`, but argument type of `putwchar()`, `fputwc()` and `putwc()` is `wchar_t`? See also [this](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20639) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655296/inconsistency-in-definitions-of-fputwc-putwc-and-putwchar-in-glibc).

Comment: As your second link says its because `wchar_t` has to be able to store meta values such as EOF, but `char` does not. So the ones that would take `char` need to take `int` instead so that meta values can be transmitted. This is fairly common in c.

Comment: @LambdaBeta the first sentence of the second link flatly contradicts the rest of the answer and is factually wrong.

Comment: @LambdaBeta why on earth **wint_t** was introduced then?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko: `wint_t` was introduced because `wchar_t` might be a type subject to 'default promotion' rules when passed to `printf()` et al.  The standard notes that `wint_t` might be the same type as `wchar_t`, but if `wchar_t` is a (16-bit) `short`, `wint_t` might be (32-bit) `int`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "`wchar_t` might be a type subject to 'default promotion' rules when passed to `printf()` et al" - please add this with an example as the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601645/how-to-change-wchar-h-to-make-wchar-t-the-same-type-as-wint-t so that I could upvote

Comment: I've added 'default promotion' rules to the answer — quoting the standard.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is 'legacy' (or 'history').  Before the C90 standard, there were no function prototypes and all arguments to all functions were subject to default promotion rules, so a `char` was automatically passed as an `int` (`short` was promoted to `int` too, and `float` to `double`, and similarly for unsigned types).  The standard couldn't afford to break existing code, so it kept that type for these functions.  It makes very little difference in practice.  The value you pass will be treated as a character type even if you pass a value that's out of range. The specification of `fputc(int c, FILE *stream)` says:

> The `fputc` function writes the character specified by `c` (converted to an `unsigned char`) to the output stream pointed to by `stream` …

### Default promotion rules

> #### §6.5.2.2 Function calls
>
> ¶6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a
>   prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that
>   have type float are promoted to double. These are called the *default argument
>   promotions.* …
>
> ¶7 … The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument
>   promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

Integer promotions are defined in §6.3.1

> ¶2 The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of `int` and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
>   bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the *integer promotions*.<sup>58)</sup> All other types are unchanged by the
>   integer promotions.
>
> ¶3 The integer promotions preserve value including sign. As discussed earlier, whether a
>   'plain' `char` is treated as signed is implementation-defined.
>
> <sup>58)</sup> The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain
>   argument expressions, to the operands of the unary `+`, `-`, and `~` operators, and to both operands of the
>   shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses.

The integer ranks are defined in ¶1 of the section in 10 bullet points.

Comment: @chux I checked and indeed, `putchar(EOF);` outputs `0xff`

Comment: @IgorLiferenko: Yes, but checking what it does on your system doesn't really prove anything. The standard says that `putchar(c)` is equivalent to `putc(c, stdout)`, which in turn is very nearly equivalent to `fputc(c, stdout)`. `fputc` is specified to convert its first argument to `unsigned char`. `EOF` is typically `-1` (though that's not guaranteed), and converting that value to `unsigned char` yields `UCHAR_MAX`, which is typicaly `0xff`. In any case, there's not much point in passing `EOF` to `putchar()`.

Comment: @KeithThompson It was to illustrate the comment which was removed, that that the argument to `fputc()` is converted to `unsigned char` no matter if `int` or `signed char` variable is passed to `fputc()`. And I used `EOF` in the role of a negative number, because it is known to be `-1` on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Jonathan's answer is too simple. Things are slightly more rational. I think that none of the library functions which handle single
characters work with `char` (only with `int`), because even though some of them do not use `EOF`, we cannot make its type `char` without
getting type conversion warnings like

```
void f(char c) { ...
...
char x = 't';
f((unsigned char)x);
...

warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘unsigned char’ may change the sign of the result
```

(because people usually typecast to unsigned char to ensure portability of the code, considering the fact that the signedness of `char` is undefined.)
So the only option was to make it `int`.