# Why argument type of `putwchar()`, `fputwc()` and `putwc()` is not `wint_t`?

Tags: c, standards, c-standard-library

The ISO C90 standard, where wchar_t was introduced, does not say
anything specific about the representation. It only requires that
this type is capable of storing all elements of the basic character set.

Which means that `wchar_t` may well be of type `char`, and `wint_t` may be
of type `int`. Further, in some implementations `wchar_t` may be signed,
and in some - unsigned. How is the situation different from `putchar()`?

For comparison, the argument of `putchar()`, `putc()` and `fputc()`
was chosen to be `int`.

I think that none of the library functions which handle single
characters work with `char` (only with `int`), because even though
some of them do not use EOF (like `putchar()`), we cannot make its type `char`,
because if it was `char`, and we typecast to `unsigned char` (the signedness of `char` is not standardized), there would be type
conversion warnings like

```
void f(char c) { ...
...
int x = 't';
f((unsigned char)x);
...

warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘unsigned char’ may change the sign of the result
```

So the only option was to make it `int`, which can hold both signed and unsigned `char`.

Although the argument is automatically converted to `unsigned char` by putchar() even if
it was passed as int or signed char, nothing of the sort is done in putwchar().

So, why `fputwc()`, `putwc()` and `putwchar()` take `wchar_t`, not `wint_t`? Seems like a flaw in the standard. Am I missing something obvious?

See also [Why islower() and friends are required to handle EOF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716908/) and [Why argument type of `putchar()`, `fputc()` and `putc()` is not `char`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40712493/) and [Inconsistency in definitions of fputwc(), putwc() and putwchar() in glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655296/)

---

**UPDATE**

some quotations from glibc reference

> if `wchar_t` is defined as `char` the type `wint_t` must be defined as `int` due to the parameter promotion.

> it would be legitimate to define `wchar_t` as `char`

Is fact, these functions had correct interfaces in "ISO Working Paper SC22/WG14/N204 dated 31st March 1992" (which is the final draft before publishing "ISO/IEC 9899:1990/Amendment 1:1995"), but they were changed in "ISO/IEC 9899:1990/Amendment 1:1995". See here http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/login_mse.html

Answer (score 2):

It is an interesting question, but unfortunately I think that the answer is just *for historical reasons*. The remainder of this answer is only my opinion, I have no references for it.

The `fputc` family exists since the first versions of K&R C, where prototypes for functions did not even exist: you should *know* what parameter types a function accepted and no implicit conversion could occur in function calls. As the `fgetc` family was returning an int, it was decided that the symmetric `fputc` one will take an int as parameter to allow the following construct:

```
fputc(fgetc(fd1), fd2);
```

If `fputc` had taken a char, it should have been written (K&R C): `fputc((char) fgetc(fd1), fd2);`.

But now, only dinosaurs can remember from K&R and implicit conversions do occur in function calls. So when the wide character set functions were added to the standard library, it was decided to only pass the part that was used to avoid a double conversion `wchar_t` -> `wint_t` -> `wchar_t` because only a `wchar_t` is used. And it is explicit in `fputs` definition (emphasize mine):

> `int fputc(int c, FILE *stream);`
>   Description: The fputc function writes the character specified by c (**converted to an unsigned
>   char**) to the output stream pointed to by stream...

So it is not very coherent, but I suppose that nobody really thought necessary to change the definition of the old `fputc` family functions...

Comment: The definition of `fputc` is correct, it need not be changed - read the rationale in OP and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40732303/1487773/ And `fputwc` is incorrect - for the very same reason (because wchar_t is no different from char - see OP)

Comment: All functions for wide characters must be analogous to functions for ordinary characters, excluding the cases where automatic promotion plays the role.